# When holding shift + scaling a shape layer = doesn't constrain a perfect shape.

Tags: cs6, shapes, adobe-after-effects

I'm on AE CS6 and when I'm scaling a shape layer it doesn't scale perfectly.

For instance, I'm scaling an ellipse shape and I want a perfect circle, usually all I have to do is hold the shift key and drag the shape to create a perfect circle.

Instead it's being constrained to an oval! Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Welcome Mark! Do you have Caps lock turned on?

Comment: Hello... No I don't.

Answer (score 4):

The Shift key constrains proportions. If you start with an oval, it will continue to be an ellipse as you scale it.

To turn an ellipse into a circle, or a rectangle into a square, adjust the height and width properties manually (be sure that auto-keyframe is turned off if you don't want to make this part of an animation) so they are the same.

Comment: I'm trying to constrain the proportions as a circle- while holding shift; instead when holding shift it constrains as an oval. I opened AE CS5 my method works just fine.... There must be something wrong with my CS6 setting.

Comment: That's likely. At any rate, you can always work numerically using the object's properties, and scrub to enlarge/reduce. I tend to use properties more than WYSIWIG scaling, so perhaps I'm a bit biased. :)

Answer (score 0):

***GO TO UR COMP SETTINGS AND SELECT SQUARE PIXELS ***

> `Lol for the answer`
>
> [image]

Comment: +1 for plausible answer but flagged for low quality (spelling, lack of further explanation, tone...)